# sendmail: deny all, allow only matched recipients

Tags: linux, sendmail, centos5

Warning: Total Sendmail noob here.

Is there anyway to restrict sendmail so that it can only send mail to specific email addresses, either by list or pattern (preferred)

Ideally I'd like to be able to specify addresses such as `test*@host.com`, however if i need to specify individual addresses such as `test1@host.com`, `test2@host.com` then so be it.

I'm not necessarily glued to Sendmail so if I need to use a different system to achieve the above I'm open to it.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like following in /etc/mail/access

```
To:test1@host.com RELAY
To:test2@host.com RELAY
From:com REJECT
From:net REJECT
From:org REJECT
... (list all TLDs to REJECT)
```